# ASP MVC 3 - Using key/value pair to populate typeahead.js dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to create a drop down list that, for each item, lists an agent name and id on one line, and some ancillary information on the line below (exactly like you see in the [typeahead.js demo page](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).

I'm trying to start off simple by passing the information from my ASP MVC controller to my view, and then displaying one piece of information (the agent's first name). The as I step through the code, I can see that I create an array of the objects that I need correctly, and then exit the controller method without incident.

Secondly, when I look at the request in Fiddler I can see that all the data I need is being returned, and in the proper format. However...

I have looked at almost every tutorial as well and I cannot seem to figure out how to display the information properly.

Here is my most recent attempt. I'm simplifying things to just be able to cycle through the array and pick out one item for display.

View Code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://blattchat.com/demos/typeahead/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        // Workaround for bug in mouse item selection
        $.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.blur = function () {
            var that = this;
            setTimeout(function () { that.hide() }, 250);
        };

        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Agent/GetAgents")';

                return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {

                    var agents = [];
                    var map = {};

                    $.each(data, function (i, agent) {
                        map[agent.FirstName] = agent;
                        agents.push(agent.FirstName);
                    });

                    return process(agents);
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $.post('@Url.Action("Details","Agent")', { id: atrVal });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Code from the Controller

```
    public JsonResult GetAgents(string term)
    {

            term = term.ToUpper();

                var lastAgents = from l in db.Agent
                                 where l.FirstName.Contains(term) ||
                                       l.LastName.Contains(term)
                                 select new
                                            {
                                                Name = l.FirstName,
                                                SymetraNumber = l.SymetraNumber,
                                             };


                var corp2Agents = from c in db.Agent
                                  where c.CorporateName.Contains(term)
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Name = c.CorporateName,
                                      SymetraNumber = c.SymetraNumber,
                                  };

                return new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = (lastAgents.Union(corp2Agents).ToArray()),
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
    }
```

And here is a screen shot of what is returned via Fiddler

[image]

Again, I am not seeing any error messages either in Visual Studio or Chrome's debugger so I think I'm just not processing the data correctly in the `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using this syntax

```
        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Agent/GetAgents")';
                var agents = [];
                map = {};

                return ($.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        map[item.Name] = item;
                        agents.push(item.Name);
                    });

                    process(agents);
                }));
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI: what you are working with is NOT typeahead.js, it's bootstrap-typeahead.js.  Different animal.  Both Bootstrap and Typeahead.js are from Twitter.  Bootstrap 3.0 has dropped support for bootstrap-typeahead.js in favor of typeahead.js.  Maybe that's one reason you didn't get much help?